# How to add Android actionmenu text

Tags: android

How to add a text view in my Action bar to show data in android application.
Following is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_log"
        android:title="@string/action_log"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/account_log"
        android:title="@string/accountlog"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
    </menu>
</menu>
```

Any changes required in strings.xml?

Comment: your question is not clear. can you pl elaborate it more. Do you want to display both menu text and icon for actionmenu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Using custom action bar Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Please check the correct case of ifRoom, I am not quite sure.

Comment: hi @chitti I need to add current user name in the action bar

Comment: In your `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method, do the following.
First find the item you need by using `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.someid);`
Then do `item.setTitle(username);` where username is the required String.